# Netsuite Scripting - Client Script ? - Remove Save Button

Tags: javascript, netsuite

So I'm working in an NetSuite admin position, thats currently 8 months post go live.

I need to prevent the saving of a record if a given customer is on the Record fields with the exception of Case records. this will prevent general users creating sales orders for the below customer and so forth in error.

our customer is '1 Anonymous customer'

in past cases where button removal has been required its been done via Workflow,
however the Default NetSuite 'Save' Button is not in the drop down of options.. however the likes of save & Bill are, which is frustrating.

this is my first attempt at scripting from dissecting other script work to get something close to what I need.

A. i dont know if this is close to everything that's required.

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ClientScript
 * Version    Date            Author            Remarks
 * 1.00       27/02/2023      Rayne     Initial Development
 *
 * 
 */
   define(['N/record'], function (record) {
   function saveRecord(context) {
       var currentRecord = context.currentRecord;
       var Entity = currentRecord.getValue({
           fieldId: 'Entity'
       });
       {if (1 Anonymous Customer)
           return false;
       }else {
           return true;
       }
   }
   return {
       pageInit: pageInit,
       saveRecord: saveRecord
   }
});
```

B. Currently the above throws an error in Sand box.
when I go customisation > Scripts > New > upload script

Fail to evaluate script: {"type":"error.SuiteScriptModuleLoaderError","name":"UNEXPECTED_ERROR","message":"syntax error (SS_SCRIPT_FOR_METADATA#15)","stack":[]}

i've tried a few variations of the attached script created in sublime text.

I've Revised the below following the comments provide.

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ClientScript
 * Version    Date            Author            Remarks
 * 1.00       27/02/2023      Rayne     Initial Development
 *
 * 
 */
  define(['N/record'], function (record) {
   function saveRecord(context) {
       var currentRecord = context.currentRecord;
       var Entity = currentRecord.getValue({
           fieldId: 'Entity'
       });
       {if (Entity == {{7}}) {
        dialog.alert({
               title: 'Unable to Save',
               message: 'Cannot Save Record Due to Anonymous Customer Being Present'
       });    
           return false;
       }else {
           return true;
       }
   }
   return {
       pageInit: pageInit,
       saveRecord: saveRecord
   }
});
```

Revised V 3.

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ClientScript
 * Version    Date            Author            Remarks
 * 1.00       27/02/2023      Rayne     Initial Development
 *
 * 
 */
  define(['N/record', 'N/ui/dialog'], function (record, dialog) {
   function saveRecord(context) {
       var currentRecord = context.currentRecord;
       var Entity = currentRecord.getValue({
           fieldId: 'Entity'
       });
       if (Entity == 7) {
        dialog.alert({
               title: 'Unable to Save',
               message: 'Cannot Save Record Due to Anonymous Customer Being Present'
       });    
           return false;
       }else {
           return true;
       }
   }
   return {
       pageInit: pageInit,
       saveRecord: saveRecord
   }
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVoHi.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the correct approach here, but as the error message says, you have a syntax error.

This line: `{if (1 Anonymous Customer)` should have the brace (`{`) at the end rather than the beginning of the line: `if (1 Anonymous Customer) {`

Note that this will not remove the Save button, but rather prevent the record from being saved when the button is clicked.  You may want to return a message so the user knows what's happening and why.

Also, I'm assuming you are using "1 Anonymous Customer" as placeholder for a properly written conditional, but if not you will also have to reformat that to something like `if (Entity == {{internalid}}) {` where `{{internalid}}` is the internal ID of the customer.  Alternatively you could change the `Entity` assignment to use getText(...) instead of getValue(...) and then `if (Entity == "1 Anonymous Customer") {`

Comment: Hi Krypton, thank you for the response.

The 1 Anonymous Customer is a select from a drop down list field within the record, 
by placeholder you mean this is not just a free text box?

i think i might look at the gettext resposne if the above appears to be an issue

I think the Return message is a brilliant idea, which i'll look at developing once i'm happy that the concept is working.

Comment: By "placeholder" I mean something you used in your example that's taking the place of actual code, because simply using "1 Anonymous Customer" as a condition will not work.  A condition in an `if` block needs to return `true` or `false`.  In a NetSuite select (drop-down) field there are two values - the internal ID which is retrieved using `getValue()` and the human-readable text value which is retrieved using `getText()`.  HTH.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance @Krypton I've revised the original following your comments and updated the original post following your comments regarding the Alert & changing the placeholder to the internal ID.

i look forward to your comments regarding the revised.

Comment: `{if (Entity == {{7}}) {` should be `if (Entity == 7) {`.  Also note that now you're using `dialog.alert()` without including the `N/ui/dialog` module which will result in another error.  `define(['N/record'], function (record) {` will need to be updated to `define(['N/record', 'N/ui/dialog'], function (record, dialog) {`

Comment: Hi Krypton. Thanks for the continued assistance, i've added a revised Code Sample above. i've added in the additional code, however when uploading to the file cabinet its now throwing this error. Fail to evaluate script: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "pageInit" is not defined. (SS_SCRIPT_FOR_METADATA#25) which refers to Line: Return { above PageInit: i feel this is a Bracket issue ? –  Strange thats it now not uploading to the file cabinet as it was before.

Comment: As the error message says: "pageInit" is not defined.  In your `return` block, you are telling the script to `return` a property named `pageInit` with a value of `pageInit` - `pageInit: pageInit`.  The value for `pageInit` is not defined anywhere in the script. Compare the line `saveRecord: saveRecord` - you _do_ have a value (a function) called `saveRecord`.  Remove the line `pageInit: pageInit`.

Comment: The script was successfully pulled into the system following removing the pageInit.
reviewing the deployment I've set it to Blank, Create , Edit
with Audience of '' All Roles'' 

no triggers appear to cause this to prevent saving or trigger the dialogue box.

Dont know where to investigate next. 

Image included of settings on the script

Comment: Log the value of `Entity` before the `if` and place another log just after the if condition to ensure the condition is met and the script is entering the if block.